# Is returning an object by reference from a c++-function exception safe?

Tags: c++

Is returning an object by (constant) reference from a c++-function generally exception safe - no matter which kind of object (e.g. class object with throwing copy-ctor) is returned? Two example cases:

Example1:

```
const T& f(const T& parm) {exception_safe_code; return parm;}
```

Example2:

```
template <typename T> struct X{ T t; T& get(){return t;} };
```

Comment: You mean a local object? Then no, it's a UB.

Comment: Most likely he means something like " `const T& f(const T& parm) { exception_safe_code; return parm;}`. ¿Is it exception safe for all types T? " But OP should clarify. I think it is exception safe for any type but I am not confident.

Comment: No, not a local one; assume, e.g., you return a class member from a (constant) member function by (constant) reference.

Comment: The process of returning can't throw, if that's what you mean.  The expression supplied in the return statement might throw (e.g. `return dynamic_cast<D &>(b);` when `b` does not refer to a `D`)

Comment: VTC: please provide code snippet illustrating your point. Right now it is unclear what you mean.

Comment: @M.M. So the example Jose Antonio Dura Olmos gave is indeed exception safe?

Comment: @Teilhart i'm not sure what you mean by "exception safe" here, but the return statement can't throw in that example

Comment: Example 2 is safe and common practice. however in Example 1 parm might be a temporary object depending on the caller.

Comment: @stefan: even if it is, `f` can be `noexcept`. The eventual exception will be thrown on the caller side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're returning a reference to an object that will still be alive outside of the function scope, and that the function doesn't have any potentially-throwing code before the `return`, then... **yes**, returning a reference cannot ever throw an exception.

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string x;
    const auto& get_x() noexcept { return x; }
//                      ^^^^^^^^
//                      Safe and recommended.
};
```

---

You added some examples - both `f` and `get` are exception-safe and can be marked as `noexcept`.